# Replace more than one element in Pyspark

Tags: regex, pyspark

I want to replace parts of a string in Pyspark using regexp_replace such as 'www.' and '.com'. Is it possible to pass list of elements to be replaced?

```
my_list = ['www.google.com', 'google.com','www.goole']
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
df = sc.parallelize(my_list).map(lambda x: Row(url = x)).toDF()
df.withColumn('site', regexp_replace('url', 'www.', '')).show()
```

I want to replace both www. and .com in the above example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a pipe `|` (OR) to combine the two patterns into a single regex pattern `www\.|\.com`, which will match `www.` or `.com`, notice you need to escape `.` to match it literally [since `.` matches (almost) any character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) in regex:

```
df.withColumn('site', regexp_replace('url', 'www\.|\.com', '')).show()
+--------------+------+
|           url|  site|
+--------------+------+
|www.google.com|google|
|    google.com|google|
|     www.goole| goole|
+--------------+------+
```